# Weighbridge data output format

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, device, tcomport

I'm developing a weighbridge software for my client using vb.net 2008. As I don't have a weighbridge device to test, I don't know the output data format which is sent to COM port by the weighbridge device. So please tell me how can I resolve the problem and get the weight value from the COM port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two apps, fortunatelly both can be found as a freeware:

- COM Port data emulator http://www.aggsoft.com/com-port-emulator.htm
- Virtual Serial Ports Emulator http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html

First run `Virtual Serial Ports Emulator` and create Connector type device, e.g. on COM10. This enables one app send data to virtual serial port which can be then opened and consumed by the second app.

Then run `COM Port data emulator` and setup for virtual serial port created previously, e.g. COM10. Setup desired COM port parameters and specify what data and how should be sent to the virtual serial port connector.

Then just connect your app to COM10 and you are done.

If you are looking for some further inspiration, check my open source project [NetWiCo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netwico/).

Comment: Hello sorry for late comment but can you tell me what kind of data does weighbride gives in the COM port and how to decode it?

Comment: Usually ascii data in some custom format, that contains string with weight number & other info like if the scales are in equilibrium etc. Most practical is to setup weight indicator to send data periodically to the COM port with settings like baud rate, parity, stop bites... Decode it by finding the number string in the data stream and convert it to number

Comment: So i guess without the manuals of the weighbride its not possible to guess which is the actual weight data.

Comment: There is an utility http://kmtronic.com/watch-data-flow-through-serial-ports-with-serial-watcher.html that can help you, set it to ASCII. But the indicator must send the data periodically. Manuals are a very good thing here though.